# What is the user agent string for iPhone 7 plus?

Tags: iphone, user-agent

I found this user agent string using Google for the iPhone 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A5297c Safari/602.1
```

What is the user agent string for the iPhone 7 PLUS?  Is there any difference?

Comment: Did you ever find out the iPhone 7 user agent strings?

Comment: No, no one ever responded with the iPhone 7 plus user agent string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here it is with iOS 10.2.1. The main difference is the model number: 14D27.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1
```